# Visual Studio not checking files into TFS from Workspace Mapping to Two TFS Servers

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I can successfully connect to my TFS server and check files out. However, the files will not check in. VS just sits on the 'Pending Changes' tab saying 'Checking in x items'.

When i view performance monitor, i can see that there is no network activity.

My workspace contains projects from two different TFS servers. Could this be the problem? It was working 2 days ago..

Comment: Two servers is a good bet as to the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try creating a second workspace and separate them.

Answer (score 0):

All good now. There were issues with TFS (which was out of my control).